# Load external javascript file after onload()

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I use this in the `head` tag:

```
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to remove this off the header and load this file with `onload()`?

```
<body onload="...">...</body>
```

Note: This is not a function, it's an external js file with several functions.

Thanks!

Comment: just add "Async" and "defer" attribute to your JS tag Eg:
"<script src="js/lightbox.js" defer async="async"></script>" this will load when ever you call a function inside it.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
function loadJS(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.async = true;
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
        var state = s.readyState;
        if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            callback.done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
loadJS('/script/script.js', function() { 
    // put your code here to run after script is loaded
});
</script>
```

I still think its better to load in jQuery and use $.getScript instead as you have lots of goodies there.

Can call this on body load

Answer (score 2):

```
onload="blabla();"

function blabla()
{
    $.getScript( 'url to your js file', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        // do some stuff after script is loaded
    });
}
```

You can learn more here

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it without jQuery, use this

```
function addScript(filename)
{
 var scriptBlock=document.createElement('script')
 scriptBlock.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
 scriptBlock.setAttribute("src", filename)
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptBlock)
}
```

and call it with `<body onload="addScript('myFile.js')"`. If you have multiple files to load, you could put in a wrapper, that adds all the files you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use $(document).ready()
and from this function load javascript. It sounds crazy but can be done. please follow http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Answer (score 0):

```
var JS = {
  load: function(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
        loaded;
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    if (callback) {
      script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function() {
        if (!loaded) {
          callback();
        }
        loaded = true;
      };
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
};

// Example with callback

JS.load("http://www.someawesomedomain.com/some.js", function() {
    //Do your thing.
});
```